# Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller:5000/v3

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, openstack-glance

When trying to setup a controller node for openstack USSURI version. I'm asked to setup glance service as VM images management sub-service.

As of requirement : [article](https://docs.openstack.org/glance/ussuri/install/install-ubuntu.html) (under ubuntu 18.04) :

1. I created a file named : admin-openrc.sh , under location : /usr/share/keystone , with content :

   ```
   export OS_USERNAME=admin 

   export OS_PASSWORD=ADMIN_PASS 

   export OS_PROJECT_NAME=admin 

   export OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=Default export OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=Default 

   export OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:5000/v3 

   export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
   ```

where ADMIN_PASS is customized

2. Type cmd : `source ./admin-openrc.sh`
3. Then, create glance user with cmd : `openstack user create --domain default --password-prompt glance`

as output, I receive error message :

```
Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://controller:5000/v3. Attempting to parse version from URL.
Unable to establish connection to http://controller:5000/v3/auth/tokens: HTTPConnectionPool(host='controller', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/auth/tokens (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa20bba02b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

Would anybody advise please ? I completed previously all steps : NTP install, openstack packages download, SQL install, RabbitMQ install, Memcached install, Etcd install, Keystone install (USSURI version)

It seems to be authentication issue maybe or something else ?

Comment: what about in terminal - ping controller
Did you missed hosts file entry.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Openstack Victoria, Ubuntu 20.04(Focal Fossa). I followed all the guides on the OpenStack documentation. https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/install-overview.html.

From my search, I found that adding the CA certificate to the environment variables worked for some people but not for me.

```
 export OS_CACERT=/path/to/ca.crt
```

you can also read https://docs.openstack.org/project-deploy-guide/charm-deployment-guide/latest/app-certificate-management.html for more info.

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP doesn't (or *didn't*, since the problem occurred six months ago) seem to be using https. Thus, certificates are not involved.